# my buildings aren't extruding in arcgis 3D

Tags: arcgis

I'm new to this, but I'm trying to make a 3D map of a street in a semi-obscure Pennsylvania town. I have a geojson file that specifies the real estate parcels and their data, but not heights or elevations of buildings. I'm using ArcGis developer. When the page renders, I get the parcels as seen from the angle I designated, but the buildings don't extrude properly. Since I am modifying code I found online, I have probably included some things that aren't applicable to my page. I've made a codepen, but it doesn't show the extrusion at all: https://codepen.io/lschneiderman/pen/mdVJbOm?editors=0011

I'm getting these error messages:

```
[esri.layers.graphics.sources.GeoJSONSource] Some fields types couldn't be inferred from the features and were dropped 

dojo.js:253 [esri.views.3d.layers.graphics.Graphics3DCore] Graphic in layer 17285dfb501-layer-0 has no symbol and will not render
```

My HTML:

```
 <div id="viewDiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

JS:

```
require([
              "esri/Map",
              "esri/views/SceneView",
              "esri/layers/GeoJSONLayer",
              "esri/layers/SceneLayer"
            ], function(Map, SceneView, GeoJSONLayer, SceneLayer) {
              const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
                url:
                  "https://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/mckeesport-fifth-ave/data/parcels-fifth1922.geojson"
              });

              geojsonLayer.elevationInfo = {
                mode: "relative-to-ground",
                featureExpressionInfo: {
                  expression: "$feature.elevation"
                },
                unit: "feet"
              };

              const heightVV = {
                type: "size",
                valueExpression: "$feature.height",
                valueUnit: "feet"
              };

              geojsonLayer.renderer = {
                type: "unique-value",
                field: "CLASSDESC__asmt",
                uniqueValueInfos: [
                  {
                    value: "COMMERCIAL",
                    symbol: {
                      type: "polygon-3d",
                      symbolLayers: [
                        {
                          type: "extrude",
                          material: {
                            color: "#D06152"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    value: "RESIDENTIAL",
                    symbol: {
                      type: "polygon-3d",
                      symbolLayers: [
                        {
                          type: "extrude",
                          material: {
                            color: "#4A9B89"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                visualVariables: [heightVV]
              };

              const map = new Map({
                basemap: "gray-vector",
                ground: "world-elevation",
                layers: [
                  geojsonLayer,
                  new SceneLayer({
                    url:
                      "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/cFEFS0EWrhfDeVw9/arcgis/rest/services/Buildings_Manhattan/SceneServer",
                    renderer: {
                      type: "simple",
                          symbol: {
                            type: "mesh-3d",
                                symbolLayers: [
                                      {
                                        type: "fill",
                                        material: {
                                          color: "white"
                                        },
                                        edges: {
                                          type: "solid",
                                          color: [100, 100, 100, 0.5],
                                          size: 0.5
                                        }
                                      }
                                ]
                          } //end symbol, line 93
                      } //end renderer
                  })//end SceneLayer
              ] //end layers
            });


              const view = new SceneView({
               container: "viewDiv",
                map: map
              });

            view.goTo({
              target: [-79.869331, 40.350433], // coordinates of crossing
              heading: 90,
              tilt: 45,
                zoom: 30 // instead of a z-value, we provide the zoom level
            }, {
              duration: 0 // tell view not to animate camera movement
            });     
        });
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided sample has the following issues:

#### Missing CORS headers

The API tries to load the GeoJSON but the browser denies it with the following error message:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/mckeesport-fifth-ave/data/parcels-fifth1922.geojson' from origin 'https://cdpn.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

You must either host the GeoJSON file on the same host the script is running or add [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers to the server hosting the GeoJSON file. For the CodePen below I downloaded the GeoJSON and uploaded it again as a CodePen asset, where CORS headers are properly set to make this work:

```js
const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
  url: "https://assets.codepen.io/2969649/parcels-fifth1922.geojson"
});
```

### Missing height attribute for extrusion

The features (in this case parcels) listed in the GeoJSON have no height information. The provided sample uses a size visual variable to extrude the polygons by the height attribute:

```js
const heightVV = {
  type: "size",
  valueExpression: "$feature.height",
  valueUnit: "feet"
};
```

Because there is no attribute named `height`, all polygons are extruded 0 feet. You can either add a corresponding attribute to all the features in the GeoJSON or simply define a constant in the sample that will be applied to all extruded polygons:

```js
geojsonLayer.renderer = {
  type: "simple",
  symbol: {
    type: "polygon-3d",
    symbolLayers: [{
      type: "extrude",
      size: 50,  // extrude all buildings by 50 meters
      material: {
        color: "#D06152"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

See the following CodePen for a working version with the above parcels:
https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/474ecc855475ced8d50f3f121988649f?editors=0010

You might want to check out the following ArcGIS API for JavaScript resources:

- [Sample: extruding building footprints](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/visualization-buildings-3d/index.html)
- [Fundamentals for Building 3D Web Apps (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zo3wPofGN-0&t=1587s)
- [Practical Guide for Building a 3D Web App from 2D Data (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0fyj4vPSCg)

Comment: Thank you *so* much!!